# The liminf of an expression involving an irrational rotation

Tags: nt.number-theory, ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, diophantine-approximation

Let $0 < a < 1$ be an irrational number. Is it true that

$$\liminf_{n \in \mathbb N, n \to \infty} n \{na\} = 0?$$

*Note: Here $\{\cdot\}$ denotes the fractional part.*

Comment: This is equivalent to the unboundedness of the terms in the continued fraction of $a$ (up to some technicalities), so in particular it is false for the quadratic irrationals such as $\phi$ or $\sqrt{2}$. But I think this question is more appropriate to math stackexchange.

Comment: @AlekseiKulikov Right, please feel free to migrate the question. Do you think the corresponding question asking if it’s true for almost all irrationals is worth asking here? (I will make a new post, of course.)

Comment: @NateRiver a generic geodesic on $SL_{2}(\mathbb{R})/SL_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$ is equidistributed and in particular unbounded. For a number to be badly approximable, one needs the geodesic to be bounded.

Comment: There are countably many $a\in\mathbb{R}$ for which $\liminf n\{na\}$ exceeds $1/3$, and there are continuum many  $a\in\mathbb{R}$ for which $\liminf n\{na\}$ equals $1/3$. See Cassels: An introduction to diophantine approximation (1957). Keyword: Markov spectrum (aka Markoff spectrum).

Comment: @GHfromMO Thanks for the reference! Very interesting result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is no, because for some real $c>0$ and all integers $q>0$ we have
$$q\{q\sqrt2\}=q(q\sqrt2-\lfloor q\sqrt2\rfloor)
=q|q\sqrt2-\lfloor q\sqrt2\rfloor| \\
\ge q\,\inf_{p\in\mathbb Z}|q\sqrt 2-p|
=q^2\,\inf_{p\in\mathbb Z}|\sqrt 2-p/q|\ge c.$$
So, $\liminf\limits_{q\to\infty} q\{q\sqrt2\}\ge c>0$.

More specifically, letting $p:=p_q:=\lfloor q\sqrt2\rfloor$ and $q\to\infty$, we have $p<q\sqrt2$, $p\sim q\sqrt2$, and hence
$$q\{q\sqrt2\}=q(q\sqrt2-p)
=q\frac{2q^2-p^2}{q\sqrt2+p} 
\ge q\frac1{q\sqrt2+p}\sim\frac1{2\sqrt2}.$$
So,
$$\liminf_{q\to\infty} q\{q\sqrt2\}\ge\frac1{2\sqrt2}>0.$$

Comment: Sorry, why is $q$ times the infimum bounded below? Is this to do with the irrationality measure being $2$?

Comment: @NateRiver See, e.g., my comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4657382/showing-that-there-exists-infinitely-many-rational-numbers-fracpq-satisfy#comment9842983_4657382).

Comment: Ahh, thank you. It is clear now. I wonder if this at least holds for almost all irrationals, since this property seems specific to quadratic irrationals as mentioned.

Comment: @NateRiver See my comment below the original post.

Comment: @NateRiver Yes, it should be an exercise to show it holds for almost all irrationals (equivalently, almost all reals).

Comment: @mathworker21 Would you mind providing a quick hint? I thought of using the result that almost all reals have irrationality measure $2$, but it seems like this on its own is not sufficient to prove the result…

Comment: @NateRiver Ok, I was wrong. Was thinking of the reverse. Look up the proof of Duffin-Schaeffer by Koukoulopoulos-Maynard for background.

Comment: @mathworker21 It's true that this property holds for almost all real. Khinchin proved in 1926, that if $\psi(x)$ is a positive decreasing real-valued function such that $\sum \psi(n)$ diverges, then for almost all real $\theta$ the inequality $\{q\theta\}<\psi(q)$ has infinitely many solutions. See Cassels's book mentioned by GH, Chapter 7.